# Viewing GPX files with XML Language Support by Red Hat extension for VSCode

Tags: xml, vscode-extensions

I have XML Language Support by Red Hat extension installed in VSCode v.1.72.0, but when I open a GPX file in editor, there is no formatting taking place. I'm getting this:

[image]

How do I enable this extension for currently open file or all GPX files in general? I'm assuming that XML Language Support by Red Hat extension can pretty-format XML files, is that correct?

Comment: Opening a file usually does not format it. You either have to save it (and auto format on save is enabled) or you manually trigger formatting, e.g. via the editor context menu.

Comment: *manually trigger formatting* - that's what I'm looking for. I have a Markdown extension installed, which has an option "Reopen editor with" to render Markdown. I don't have a similar option for XML.

Comment: Formatting is provided by VS Code language extensions (not all support that, however, as you see with the Red Hat extension). So you have to find an XML extension on the marketplace, which has formatting support.

Comment: @MikeLischke Red Hat extension DOES provide formatting according to its description and it is enabled by default, but it acts only on .xml files.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue has been created [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/issues/784) and the answer is to add in the settings.json:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.gpx": "xml"
}
```

It is a settings used by vscode himself to associate file extension with language id. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers